# couchdb image attachement not showing

Tags: couchdb, attachment, cloudant

In my page (localhost),

```
 <img src="http://codingcyber.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/vivek-vengala.jpg?x52743">
```

shows this image, found on the web

I have put this image as an attachement in couchdb (cloudant):

```
    "_attachments": {
     "vivek-vengala.jpg": {
       "content_type": "image/jpeg",
       "revpos": 3,
       "digest": "md5-W2t1msSBZ4eG07hG3R0JbA==",
       "length": 47970,
       "stub": true
     },
```

but when I try to retrieve and show it :

```
<img src="https://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.cloudant.com/essai/49509f60b6f17dc567cad0233fd11916/vivek-vengala.jpg">
```

just shows an image icon, when I right click I can see it in a new window.

What is my mistake?

Comment: i tried (using your image) in my database and it worked for me. what browser are you using? do you notice any errors or warnings in the browser console and/or network logs?

Comment: I am using chrome, and here is the problem :[Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.
It works in Firefox....

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the database accessible to the public and not using your credentials in the image's URL. Anybody would be able to get access to your credentials anyway (by just checking the source code), so it's the same as deliberately making your database public.

You should create several databases within Cloudant, one with public access (maybe call it `public`), and another one with private credentials.